# Send an email/message notification on Task create on a Custom Object

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, tasks

I have a requirement where a Task is created by a third party application using REST API in my salesforce.com domain.
I want to notify a Group of users on such a scenario. 
I wanted to user workflow rules but email alerts are not allowed for Task.
The other option would be to have an Apex Trigger.

Is there any other better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email alerts are now possible on task (as of winter 16)

See: https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_task_event_workflow_email_alerts.htm

> You can now create email alerts for activities (tasks and events).
>   Once you create an email alert, you can add it to a process, workflow
>   rule, milestone, approval process, or flow.

Answer (score 0):

Use Process Builder as of Spring '15.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's a lazy answer but it's the right one. It's pretty clear what is being asked and as far as I know Process Builder is the only way to do it. Not many people know about it yet.

Comment: Can you expand on this to add some details as to how OP would go about it? You'd get a lot more votes & rep that way!